# How to write equation including `abs` inside, using Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, math, r-markdown

I have managed to write the whole equation
[image: Equation I want to write]

using the following code in Rmarkdown

```
$$MAPE = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d_i} (\frac{1}{q} \sum_{t_j} 
\abs{\frac{gap_{i,j}-s_{i,j}}{gap_{i,j}}}  )$$
```

However, in Rmarkdown, the code above returns:

[image: Rmarkdown output]

Could anyone help figure out how to get `abs` right here?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expanding on Andrie's answer:

Another way to write absolute value is 
`\lvert -3 \rvert`

To automatically adjust the size of the vertical lines to what's inside them, use

`\left\lvert -3 \right\rvert`

In your case, this becomes:

`$$MAPE = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d_i} (\frac{1}{q} \sum_{t_j}\left\lvert{\frac{gap_{i,j}-s_{i,j}}{gap_{i,j}}}\right\rvert)$$`

[image: Image of Output]

edit: When I originally posted this answer, I couldn't embed images yet. Now replaced link with embed.

Comment: I'd use `\left(` and `\right)` too, instead of `( ... )`.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. Yes, that's how I would do it, too. I just wanted to reduce the changes in the original code to a minimum here.

Comment: This solution has more to write but prettier. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using mathjax, you can use the "pipe" symbol `|`to indicate absolute values.

Try this:

```
$$ |-3| $$
```

[image]

In your case:

```
$$MAPE = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d_i} (\frac{1}{q} \sum_{t_j} |\frac{gap_{i,j}-s_{i,j}}{gap_{i,j}}|  )$$
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this straightforward solution!