# How to write an absolute value in a LaTeX equation with a table in Markdown?

Tags: latex, markdown

I want to write an absolute value within a LaTeX equation in Markdown. But the code:

```
| Name | Equation |
|---|---|
| Absolute value | $|x|$ |
```

produces (when rendered e.g. with Obsidian):

[image: Wrong rendering]

which is wrong. I see that the pipe `|` character interacts wrongly with the pipe used to format the Markdown table, but I do not see how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

An other option would be the following:

```
| Name | Equation |
|---|---|
| Absolute Value | $\|x\|$ |
```

By using `\|` the rendering is done correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possible trick is to use the `\rvert` and `\lvert` commands in LaTeX.

```
| Name | Equation |
|---|---|
| Absolute value | $\lvert x \rvert$ |
```

which produces:

[image: Correct rendering]

I had this idea while looking at this message on how to [write an equation including abs using rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411920/how-to-write-equation-including-abs-inside-using-rmarkdown).